# Categories and subcategories using Zend Framework 1

Tags: php, zend-framework, models

I want to have categories and subcategories so i created a table

categories: id, name, page_id, parent_id

This is my application/models/Categories.php model

```
<?php

class Application_Model_Categories extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'categories';
    protected $_referenceMap = array(
        'Pages' => array (
            'columns' => 'page_id',
            'refTableClass' => 'Application_Model_Pages',
            'refColumns' => 'id')
        );
}
```

This is my application/models/Pages.php model

```
<?php

class Application_Model_Pages extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = "pages"; 
    protected $_dependentTables = array('categories');
}
```

Then in my controller i call the model

```
$pages = new Application_Model_Pages();
$find = $pages->find(2456);
$current = $find->current();
$categories = $current->findDependentRowset('Application_Model_Categories');
```

This is working, but the problem is that is returning all the categories and i want only those with parent_id = 0 (if parent_id > 0 they are not categories, are subcategories -maybe i need a more appropiate table name-)

Also i want to know how to generate an array of categories and subcategories so i can return that information too

Answer (score 0):

In model categories create a function:

```
public function selectParentCategory($pID)
{
     $select = $this->select()->where("parent_id = ?", $pID);
     $row = $this->fetchAll($select);

     return $row;
}
```

then in your controller you complete the following:

```
$pID = 2456;
$pages = new Model_Pages();
$pages = $pages->selectParentCategory($pID);

$this->view->pages = $pages;
```

Comment: I´m getting Call to undefined method Application_Model_Pages:: selectParentCategory()